# How do I backup and restore my files/permissions when preparing for a remove/replace of WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

With the creators update out, I'd like to upgrade my Ubuntu instance to 16.04.

The [recommended approach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/04/11/windows-10-creators-update-whats-new-in-bashwsl-windows-console/) to upgrade (and I agree) is to remove and replace the instance with a clean installation.  However I have some files and configurations I would like to keep and transfer to the new install.  They suggest copying the files over to a Windows folder to backup the files and restore afterward.  However, by putting the files there, it messes up all the permissions of everything.

I had already done the remove/replace on one of my machines and I found that trying to restore all the permissions on all the files was just not worth it and did another clean install and will be copying the contents of the file over instead.  This will be an equally tedious solution to restore these files but it has to be done.

**Is there an easier way to backup and restore my files and their permissions when doing this upgrade?**

I have two more machines I would like to upgrade but do not want to go through this process again if it can be helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use linux way to backup your files with permission, such as `getfacl/setfacl` or `tar -p`

Comment: Well shoot, that should have been obvious. At least then, the tarball itself will have the weird permissions but the contents will retain their usual permissions. I wish the blog mentioned this instead. Shows how green I am with Linux.

Comment: Why you care about the permission of the tar file, you can put it on DrvFS /mnt/d/blablabla

Comment: Well, for the purposes of restoring the backed up files, it doesn't matter what the permissions are. I was just saying, that's exactly what I needed to hear.

Comment: In theory, there should exist Windows software can backup wsl files (files with NTFS EA info), but find such software is not easy, so just use linux way